# SQL Server : get results from one table based on search another result set

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a search page that will allow the user to return a list of employee names based on the skills they have been assigned so the user can select the best qualified technician for new jobs.

We have an `mpEmployee` table with basic name and contact information:

```
EmployeeID  FirstName   LastName
1           Nathan      G           
3           Jay         A           
6           Dawn        H           
17          Dawn        S
```

The various skills have an ID and are assigned to each employee in the `mpAssignedSkills` table in an individual record. Each employee can have multiple skills assigned.

```
AssignedSkillID EmployeeID  SkillID 
11                17          16    
18                17          14    
12                17          29    
13                17          25    
14                 1          16    
15                 1          29    
16                 1          25
```

The user needs to be able to select a set of skillIDs and it should return a listing of employees that have all those skills currently assigned.

Ive tried a number of queries using INNER JOIN, HAVING, IN and GROUP BY with no luck.  The problem seems to be in the results from the mpAssignedSkills table.  How do I return a set of distinct employeeIDs for employees that have multiple SKillIDs assigned (i.e 16, 29, 25) ?

Thanks

Comment: How are the Skill Ids stored? How do you pass the Skill Ids to the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the Ids are passed to the query, you could populate a table variable of the selected ids.

```
DECLARE @SelectedSkillIds TABLE
(
   SkillId   INT   
)
```

Then to find employees with matching skills, you can join to the table variable:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId
      ,e.FirstName
      ,e.LastName
FROM mpEmployee e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT AssignedSkillId 
              FROM mpAssignedSkills as
              INNER JOIN @SelectedSkillIds ssid ON ssid.SkillId = as.SkillId
              WHERE as.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId)
```

If there is a finite number of skills, you could try this instead:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId
      ,e.FirstName
      ,e.LastName
FROM mpEmployee e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT AssignedSkillId 
              FROM mpAssignedSkills as                  
              WHERE as.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
                AND as.SkillId IN (@SkillId1, @SkillId2, @SkillId3 /* etc.. /*
              )
```

***EDIT***: If you know the number of skills provided, an easy way would be to count the number of assigned skills that matched the search:

```
DECLARE @SkillId1 INT = 16
DECLARE @SkillId2 INT = 14
DECLARE @SkillId3 INT = 29
DECLARE @TotalSkills INT = 3

SELECT DISTINCT eas.EmployeeId
FROM mpEmployee e
   INNER JOIN mpAssignedSkills eas ON eas.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
WHERE eas.SkillId IN (@SkillId1, @SkillId2, @SkillId3)
GROUP BY eas.EmployeeId
HAVING COUNT(eas.SkillId) = @TotalSkills
```

Working example: [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3c859925ca392617540d263912fcbc2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael, the last query was close but returned names of employees with SkillID1 OR SkillID2 OR SkillID3.  If I search for employees with Skills 16 AND 29 I should get EmployeeID 1 and 17 as a result.  If I search for skills 16, 14, 29 only EmployeeID 17 should show as a result.

Comment: Genius - thats got it!  Thanks Michael!

Comment: If you feel this is the answer to your question, be sure to accept it. :)